# Change button to input form

Tags: jquery, html, button, input

How to make a button, that will change appearance/function to an input field when click on the button? Like the buttons here: [https://wake.io/](https://www.wake.io).

html

```
<div id="button">Button</div>

<form name="input" action="#" method="get" style="display: none;">
    <input type="text" id="comment" placeholder="E-mail..."/>
</form>
```

jquery

```
$('#button').click(function(){
   $(this).hide();
   $('form').show();
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7s3q3tcr/)

Comment: Have you some code?
You need to use Javascript/Jquery to do this.

Comment: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7s3q3tcr/) <- Something like this, but when click button, I have to mark the input form by clicking again. I want it to be marked directly when click button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

basically this will do the trick, but there are a lot of ways to achieve that, this is just one way. That said, the code is this:

html code:

```
<div id="button-wrapper"><button id="button">Subscribe</button></div>
```

jquery code:

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $("#button-wrapper button").click(function(){

        $("#button-wrapper").html('<input type="text" />');
        $("#button-wrapper input").focus();
    });
});
</script>
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rsscu151/1/)

Comment: Thanks Santiago!:) Is it possible in some way to make the input area marked directly when press button? Now we first have to press the button, then must "activate" the input area again by clicking.

Comment: sure, in order to do that just add `$('#comment').focus();`, look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7s3q3tcr/1/), if want to learn more jquery [check this out](http://learn.jquery.com/)

Comment: Thanks Santiago! I'm new here, and really thankful for your help!

Comment: you're welcome and that's all right, everybody's learning here so welcome to SO!